# How can I get live console output when device is connected to another hardware device?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, console

So I'm trying to make an application using the DJI SDK. In order for my app to function properly, my iDevice needs to be hooked up to the remote controller of the drone via USB.

This means I can't also run the app via xcode and get console output.

Is there a way of saving console output when using an app on your phone? I am aware of the crash logs, but sadly they don't provide enough info to be useful to me.

This problem started when I got a runtime error only when the device was connected to the remote controller. Therefore there was no way of isolating the problem since I couldn't tell what went wrong.

Another solution would maybe be a 1 female to 2 male usb chord, but I haven't found one online yet and even if I did I don't know if that would work.

Is there a standard way of debugging when using hardware that needs to be connected to the device?

Answer (score 0):

from Xcode, hit window on the tool bar at the top, then Devices.  Select the device you want to read the log from.  However, this is the log for the entire phone, and you have to be plugged into the mac... so you'll have to run your tests, unplug from the DJI, plug into the mac, go to devices, and scroll through the log until you find the output from your app, and you won't be able to see real time expected outcome.

It's not ideal, but that's the only way I know of to see the apart from building an entire console log into your app yourself.

Comment: I know but these are only crash logs, not the actual console logs outputted by print() statements et cetera

Comment: It also doesn't list the error message, just some error code and then a list of threads